# how to run postfix by hand

Tags: postfix, smtp, daemon, email-server, master

I compiled `postfix 2.9.5` with `mysql backend`.You know `postfix daemons` are ran with `postfix`, So i don't know main `postfix daemon` to run by hand. What's main daemon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's `/usr/sbin/postfix`